# Boxcox() transformation in R error

Tags: r, error-handling, time-series, transformation

```
cellphone = read.csv("/Users/crystalchau/Desktop/UICT-CELL_IND.csv", nrows = 25, colClasses = c(NA,NA,"NULL")) 

cellphone = cellphone[nrow(cellphone):1,]

cellphone.ts = ts(cellphone, frequency = 1)

ts.plot(cellphone.ts, ylab = "Mobile Cellular Telephone Subscriptions")

title(expression(Mobile~Celluar~Telephone~Subscriptions))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))

cellphone = read.csv("/Users/crystalchau/Desktop/UICT-CELL_IND.csv", nrows = 25, colClasses = c("NULL",NA,"NULL"))

cellphone = cellphone[nrow(cellphone):1,]

cellphone.ts = ts(cellphone, frequency = 1)

acf(cellphone.ts, lag.max = 10)

pacf(cellphone.ts, lag.max = 10)

cellphone.ts = ts(cellphone, frequency = 12)

decompose_cellphone = decompose(cellphone.ts, type = "multiplicative")

plot(decompose_cellphone)

library(MASS)

bcTransform = boxcox(cellphone ~ as.numeric(1:length(cellphone)), lambda = seq(-1, 1, length = 10))

plot(bcTransform, type = 'l', axes = FALSE)
```

It won't allow me to run the boxcox transformation line and gives me the error message:

> Error in boxcox.default(cellphone.ts ~
>   as.numeric(1:length(cellphone.ts)),  :    response variable must be
>   positive

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting that there are zero or infinite values in your data (in this case, `cellphone`).

'*In linear regression, box-cox transformation is widely used to transform target variable so that linearity and normality assumptions can be met. But box-cox transformation can be used only for strictly positive target values. If you have negative values in your target (dependent) variable, the box-cox and log transformation cannot be used.*' ([ref](https://www.listendata.com/2015/09/regression-transform-negative-values.html))

The error can be reproduced by adding negative values to the `iris` data set.

```
library(MASS)

data(iris)

#no negatives, no error

boxcox(iris$Petal.Width ~ as.numeric(1:length(iris$Species)), lambda = seq(-1, 1, length = 10))

#add negatives

iris$Petal.Width2<-iris$Petal.Width-5

#gives error

boxcox(iris$Petal.Width2 ~ as.numeric(1:length(iris$Species)), lambda = seq(-1, 1, length = 10))

#Error in boxcox.default(iris$Petal.Width2 ~ as.numeric(1:length(iris$Species)),  : 
#response variable must be positive
```

You might consider trying a `Yeo-Johnson` transformation instead. This is similar to a `box-cox`, but allows for negatives. ([see here](https://www.listendata.com/2015/09/regression-transform-negative-values.html))